# linux, only copy files before a certain date

Tags: linux, copy

Is there a command to only copy files before a certain date, say 20120901? Furthermore, I would like to do it with cp -p capability (e.g. the original timestamp is preserved).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do it with a combination of touch and find.

```
# Create a file with the desired timestamp
touch -d 20120901 /tmp/timefile

# Find all files older than that and act on them
find $PATH -type -f -and -not -newer /tmp/timefile -print0 | xargs -0 -i % cp -p % /new/location
```

So what this does is find all files underneath the directory `$PATH` that have been modified before September 1st, 2012 at 00:00:00 hours and copy them all to the directory `/new/location`

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the accepted answer. The `-type` should be followed by `f` and not `-f`. Also that expression didn't work for me.

This did work for me:

```
find <path> -type f -and -not -newer /tmp/timefile | xargs -I  '{}' cp -p '{}' <path/to/destination/directory>
```

To find files newer than the timestamped file, do:

```
find <path> -type f -and -newer /tmp/timefile | xargs -I  '{}' cp -p '{}' <path/to/destination/directory>
```

Additionally, if you want to filter based on a specific hour, minute and second, modify `touch` part as follows

```
touch -t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS] /tmp/timefile
```

e.g.

```
touch -t 202205040930.00 /tmp/timefile
```

Then do the `find` part.

Comment: If you find a typo in a question or an answer feel free to suggest an edit. There is no need to post the same answer again.

Comment: I cannot add a comment due to having to have a reputation of at least 50, unfortunately.